# strip escape characters using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am ajax'ing data to a Wordpress database and on success showing the text that was written to the database in a div so that people can see what was written

my code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url').'/insert_comment.php';?>",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function(html){
    var returnedArray = html.split('|');
    var newhtml = $.trim(unescape(returnedArray[0]));
    $("#quote").fadeOut(200,function(){ 
                   $("#quote_cont").text(newhtml);
                   $("#quote span").text(returnedArray[1]) });
    $("#quote").fadeIn(200);
       }
```

So for example if the user writes the comment "I don't understand!!"

div #quote displays "I don\'t understand!!", yet when i view the database it was written without the "\".. and if i pull the content straight from the database using PHP i dont get the "\"

EDIT:

changed PHP file below is now CORRECT.. many thanks to @deceze for being patient with me, make sure that your mysql_real_escape_string() comes AFTER your database connection

```
<?php  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("robomon_wbc", $con);
$order_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['order_id']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
$comment = strip_tags($comment);
mysql_query("UPDATE wp_orderdata SET `comment`='".$comment."', `cus_name` = '".$name."' WHERE `order_id`='".$order_id."' AND `order_email`='".$email."';");
mysql_close($con);
echo $_POST['comment'].'|'.$_POST['name']; ?>
```

Comment: Show us the server-side code, what exactly is returned from the call and possibly at which point exactly the slashes are added to the string. I don't think this is an issue of needing to strip escapes, but rather a problem of handling the string correctly server-side to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code to insert the comment into the database is **bad**. It relies on [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), which is the reason you're seeing slashes in the output values. Please read the aforelinked documentation about Magic Quotes, they're bad, deprecated and not recommended. Instead you need to SQL escape the values using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or use a better MySQL interface to begin with which supports prepared statements, like [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/PDO).

To summarize, the slashes are caused by Magic Quotes, which you *could* strip/disable on the server, but if you do so, you'll need to change your database code to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities. You should change your database code anyway, since you're still vulnerable to SQL injection even with Magic Quotes.

Comment: ok, thanks! i appreciate the note about security and have updated to include the mysql_real_escape_string around my variables that im handing to the query.. however this DOESNT fix the returned data from the AJAX operation still being escaped...

Comment: as i have no access to the php.ini file, added "php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off" to the .htaccess file

Comment: Did that work? Output the raw `$_POST` array. Or read the manual section, which talks about different ways of disabling/stripping magic quotes.

Comment: [disabling magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) just followed what they say.. the problem isnt from the insert_comment.php file im pretty sure its what happens to the string when it reaches the success section of the AJAX

Comment: Slashes don't just appear out of nowhere. Do some step by step debugging of where exactly they appear. Magic quotes are the most likely suspect.

Comment: ahh sorry didnt see you say about the raw `$_POST` array... :D that was the bit i was missing..

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var newhtml = $.trim(unescape(html));
```

Comment: this doesnt help unfortunately

Comment: Ok, I took your question to indicate that you wanted help with the javascript displaying backslashes.

Comment: yer not your fault mate.. i diagnosed the problem wrong.. it appeared to me to be coming from the JS, thank you though